# Search space difference between clingo and multishot solving clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am new to the area of ASP. I would like to know whether multi-shot solving will affect the overall search space, more than the classical one.

Also, does the search space of the following program relies only on the choice rules?

a:-b. {b}.

what would be the overall search space?

Also, if considering adding '{b}' in a sub-program and 'a:-b.' in another one, would this affect the overall search space?

If I am not mistaken, the search space is 2. as constant 'a' does not play a role in affecting the overall number of models.